# Changing array value in foreach on condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have a resulting array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'service' => string 'Blood Tranfusion' (length=16)
      'unit' => string '1' (length=1)
      'service_charges' => string '170' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'service' => string 'Nebulization' (length=12)
      'unit' => string '2' (length=1)
      'service_charges' => string '100' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'service' => string 'Service Charge' (length=14)
      'unit' => string '4' (length=1)
      'service_charges' => string '200' (length=3)
 3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'service' => string 'Registration Charge' (length=19)
      'unit' => string '4' (length=1)
      'service_charges' => string '200' (length=3)
```

I am outputting the result from these array is like this:

```
foreach($services as  $service){ 

     echo "<tr><td>";  
     echo $service['service'];     
     echo "</td><td>";  
     echo number_format($service['service_charges'],2);
     echo "</td><td>";
     $chargeable_service_unit=0;
     $service_unit =$service['unit'];

     if ($service_unit < $model->packagedays  ){         
         $chargeable_service_unit = 0;

     }else{
        $chargeable_service_unit = $service_unit - $model->packagedays;         
     }
     echo $chargeable_service_unit;
     echo "</td><td>";  
     $service_charges_total = (($service['service_charges'])*($chargeable_service_unit));
     $serviceTotalAmount += $service_charges_total;

     $service_charges_total_amount+=$service_charges_total;
     echo number_format($service_charges_total,2);     
     echo "</td></tr>"; 

   }
```

Now What I want is say the package days is 4 and array result is like this

```
Blood Tranfusion =1
Nebulization = 2
Service Charge = 5
```

then the final result should be

```
Blood Transfusion = 1
Nebulization = 2
Service Charge = 1
```

if service charge is 4 or less then 4 then service charge =0

I think It is little complex. I am ready to provide more detail if needed.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or an undesired result? If so, share that too.

Comment: `if ($service['service']=='Service Charges')` - I am getting `boolean` false. I expect it to be true.

Comment: @Pawan in your example result it's "Service Charge", not "Service Charges" (Note the s!)

Comment: Thanks, I updated it, but it doesn't make any difference. Still I am not able to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the array and reassign like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($services as $k => $v) {
    if ( $services[$i]['service'] === 'Service Charge' || 'Registration Charge' ) {
        $services[$i]['unit'] = '0';
    }

    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike - I have tried to use ur solution but it still returns `false` if I am trying ur qurey like `if ( $services[$i]['service'] === 'Service Charge')` even though `Service Charge` is in the array.

Comment: I have also updated my question for the condtions, where `Service Charge` needs to zero

Comment: I think you need to add more detail with what your actual goal is. If you are going to reference something, then you need to include the reference.

The code I posted, simply reassigns the value of the 'unit' key to '0' if the 'service' key was either 'Service Charge' or 'Registration Charge' which is what you originally asked for.

So the original array, "services" is updated accordingly. You then do whatever post processing you wanted to do with the updated services array.

You did not show any other process beyond that request. I'm at a loss for what it is that is returning FALSE.

Comment: Hi Mike - I have updated the question - I hope I have added the detail needed.